# How where the current temporary moderators determined?

Tags: support, questions

Today I notices that we must have some moderators on this site, as on of the questions was closed.

So by now we know some or most of the current moderators.

How did they become moderators?

Comment: For clarity: all you know are the ones unabashedly trying to help make the site better ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No temporary moderators have been appointed yet; the only moderators right now are Stack Overflow employees like myself.

[Sebastian](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71/how-where-the-current-temporary-moderators-determined/72#72) is correct though; during the beta, the [reputation requirements are reduced](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation-abilities), so anyone can vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need moderators to close questons -- once your reputation is high enough (which is 1 right now, 250 when we're out of beta), you'll get an option to vote to close -- any 5 non-moderator users can then close a question.

For example, no moderators were involved for:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/327/troubleshooting-performance-issues-closed
- [books for aspiring DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188/books-for-aspiring-dba-closed)

If there were moderators involved in a close, there would be a diamond next to the last person in the list (and typically less than 5 people in the list, as if a moderator votes, it's closed immediately)

Answer (score 2):

I think we all are, as it's a private beta? For example I could close this question. (And others)

Comment: Perhaps that depends on rep. Today having more than 200 I can too. But I don't remember to have seen the close button yesterday.

Comment: That's probably it! ;-)

Comment: No you could yesterday but nobody was using it. Since then several of us have been tagging to close. I hope you guys do too